# ES6 Promises strangely extract correct value out of custom js objects

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I've written a library that is completely separate from [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) but achieves similar goals. It uses [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and falls back to [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and has nothing common with Promises. In fact you can run it on ie9 - 10 or a machine from 2009 etc. Here is the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX/master/dist/rafx.v0.0.20.dev.js)

How is it possible that the below code works, and the 2nd promise gets the value (v + 3) correctly into the 3rd promise after 10 second delay?? Because `rafx.async...` returns a custom proprietary object.

```js
const x = Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log("2nd promise"))
.then(() => {
  //600 frames === 10 secs
  return rafx.async(6)
  .skipFrames(600)
  .then(v => v + 1)
  .then(v => v + 3);
});

console.log(x instanceof Promise);

x.then(v => console.log("3rd promise", v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rafx"></script>
```

The expectation would be that the v at `x.then(v...` would equal to whatever custom object returned from the custom `then`.

Here is what `rafx.async(6).skipFrames(600)...then(v => v + 3)` returns:

```json
prt.Thenable {....
    status: Status {thenable: prt.Thenable, instance: Rafx...
    _argObj: {value: 10, done: true},
    _breaker: {value: false}
    ....
```

The `Thenable` and `Status` constructors have nothing to do with `Promises`, they are completely custom.

To my surprise, this even works:

```js
const x = Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log("2nd promise"))
.then(() => {
  return rafx.async("hello")
  .loop(function(str){
    return str;
  })
  .until(str => window.testVar === " world!")
  .then(str => str + window.testVar);
});

console.log(x instanceof Promise);

x.then((value) => console.log("3rd promise", value))
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rafx"></script>
<button onclick="window.testVar = ' world!';">set testVar to ' world!'</button>
```

You can verify that `Promise.prototype.then !== rafx.Thenable.prototype.then`, the `then` implementation is completely separate, as seen [here](https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX/blob/master/dist/rafx.v0.0.20.dev.js#L405-L426);

**So how is it possible that `Promise` understands how my API works?????
(I am sure I am missing something awfully clear)**

<sup>PS: I replaced all arrow functions (coz of `this` binding) with regular ones, it still works, but it shouldn't..</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification for Promises is designed so that it can interoperate with other "thenables". Ie, objects that have a `.then` property which is a function. If you resolve a promise with a thenable (in your case by returning a thenable in a `.then` block), the outer promise will call that function, passing in a resolve and reject function, and will wait for the inner thenable to call resolve. Only then will the outer promise resolve.

For example:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const myThenable = {
    then: (resolve2, reject2) => {
      console.log('running .then')
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('resolving inner');
        resolve2("hello");
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  console.log('resolving outer');
  resolve(myThenable);
})

promise.then(result => {
  console.log('final result', result);
})
```

Then code you've got for your thenable wasn't designed to work with this, but apparently it does:

```
prt.Thenable.prototype.then = function(f, rest){
```

When the promise calls your `.then` function, `f` will be the resolve function, and `rest` will be the reject function. Some point down the road you are calling `f`, which happens to have the behavior you want, and apparently it didn't cause any exceptions to have `rest` be a function that you weren't expecting.

Comment: This was such a weird coincidence. I accepted the answer. Is [this](https://promisesaplus.com/#:~:text=%E2%80%9Cpromise%E2%80%9D%20is%20an%20object%20or,thrown%20using%20the%20throw%20statement.) the correct reference to what you are referring??

Comment: The Promises A+ spec used to be the spec for promises, back when they had to be done via custom libraries. So if you were using, say, [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) for your promises, it would follow Promises A+. Since 2015 though, javascript has built in promises, and their spec [can be found here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-objects). Both specs do almost the same thing, and the old one can be easier to read, so you might prefer to look at Promises A+ even though it's older.